# Match a solidity function selector with a dynamic array to a vyper function selector

Tags: solidity, vyper, function-selector

I have a solidity function selector:

```js
bytes4 selector = bytes4(keccak256(bytes("rawFulfillRandomWords(uint256,uint256[])")));
```

(The selector here is 0x1fe543e3)

And in this function selector, as you can see, we have a dynamic array.

In vyper, I'd like to call this function, but without the dynamic array (a static array).

```py
method_id("rawFulfillRandomWords(uint256,uint256[1])")
```

(The selector here is 0x4e04d708, which is wrong)

Is this possible?

Comment: Or better yet, is there a way to manually assign a function selector to a function?

Answer (score 0):

You'd use a dynamic array.

A function that looks like:

```py
def rawFulfillRandomWords(requestId: uint256, randomWords: DynArray[uint256, 10]):
```

Will have a function signature of:

```
rawFulfillRandomWords(uint256,uint256[])
```

Dynamic arrays are technically "dynamic" just with a max size - in this case the max size would be 10.